# TfidfVectorizer results in adding null rows and incorrect score assignment

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

**Question:** why does sklearn's TfidfVectorizer deliver scores attached to values that don't exist (i.e. the vectorizer creates null rows)? In addition, why are the scores not matching up to the appropriate attributes?

**Pipeline:** Bring in text data from a SQL DB, split text into bigrams and calculate the frequency per document and the tf-idf per bigram per document, load the results back into the SQL DB.

**Current State:**

Two columns of data are brought in (number, text). text is cleaned to produce a third column cleanText:

```
   number                               text              cleanText
0     123            The farmer plants grain    farmer plants grain
1     234  The farmer and his son go fishing  farmer son go fishing
2     345            The fisher catches tuna    fisher catches tuna
```

Drop rows with only one word:

```
data = data[data['cleanText'].str.contains(' ')]
```

Group, then perform feature extraction:

```
data_grouped = data.groupby('number')

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

nGrams = pd.DataFrame()

for id, group in data_grouped:
       X = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['cleanText'])
       Y = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(group['cleanText'])
       frequencies = sum(X).toarray()[0]
       Y.todense()
       tfidfscore = Y.toarray()[0]
       results = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, columns=['frequency'])
       results2 = pd.DataFrame(tfidfscore, columns=['tfidfscore'])
       dfinner = pd.DataFrame(word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['nGram'])
       dfinner['id'] = id
       results = results.join(dfinner)
       results = results2.join(results)
       nGrams = nGrams.append(results)


print(nGrams)
```

**Output:**

```
   tfidfscore  frequency           nGram     id
0     0.57735        1.0   farmer plants  123.0
1     0.57735        1.0    plants grain  123.0
2     0.57735        NaN             NaN    NaN
0     0.50000        1.0      farmer son  234.0
1     0.50000        1.0      go fishing  234.0
2     0.50000        1.0          son go  234.0
3     0.50000        NaN             NaN    NaN
0     0.57735        1.0    catches tuna  345.0
1     0.57735        1.0  fisher catches  345.0
2     0.57735        NaN             NaN    NaN
```

**Problems:**

1. output includes new rows that have null values for every column except tfidfscore
2. `tfidfscore` doesn't seem to match up. It seems like the `0.5` scores should be tied to number (id) `123` and number `345` because there are two bigrams in each of those lines (i.e. 0.5 or 50% importance each)

Why is the TfidfVectorizer adding these rows and incorrectly assigning scores to numbers? Is it something to do with indexing? Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple problem that I simply overlooked. The TfidfVectorizer was never initialized with the correct parameters that would make it work as expected. so I simply changed this line:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
```

To this:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w+\b", stop_words=None, ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
```